# Will RPi 2 with Ubuntu Snappy Core boot without monitor and keyboard

Tags: networking, boot, ssh, snappy

I just buy a Raspberry Pi 2, this is my first one! I love it!
I install Ubuntu Snappy Core, plug the monitor, keyboard, internet cable then install program and have fun.
I check that sshd is running, then I poweroff, plug off monitor, keyboard, power supply and reboot (with the internet cable).
In my router, I can check what devices connected to internet, and I don't see My RPi 2 on the list, only my laptop.
So my question is Will RPi 2 with Ubuntu Snappy Core boot or connect to interner without monitor and keyboard?

Comment: Have you asked it to connect to an internet site?  Do you mean it isn't visible to your router?

Comment: Yes, it isn't visible to my router!
Sorry I don't understand your frist question!

Comment: internet != router.  How does your Pi get its IP address?  Manually or via DHCP from the router?

Comment: :D I don't know much about network stuff. Basically when The raspberry is on with a monitor and keyboard, I can ssh to the it with my laptop (by check the raspberry ip in my router, something like 192.168.1.10). But when I try the raspberry without montor/keyboard I no longer find the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Snappy Ubuntu Core will run headless from the very first boot. It uses DHCP to obtain network configuration information from a DHCP server (such as a router or gateway) on the local network. It also runs sshd from first boot, so that you can ssh into it from another machine in order to be able to use it. Most home routers will have a web interface that will allow you to see the name/address that has been assigned to your RPi so that you know what to ssh in to. Failing that, you can use "nmap" or similar to find it.